# What is actual default value of a char in java?

Tags: java

```
class CHar
{
    public static void main(String []l)
    {
        char j='\u0000';
        System.out.println("value of char j="+j);
    }
}
```

When I print the value of j then it prints nothing it means null value, but java dic says the default value of char is '\u0000' with which I agree, but the default value should be print. Instead of printing the default value it prints

```
C:\Users\Mohit-Pc\Desktop\Java Array>java CHar
value of char j=
```

That it is nothing means null. I'm still confused, whether I use instead of char default value, null then it generates an error:

> CHar.java:5: error: incompatible types:  cannot be converted to
>   char char j=null;

Comment: Zero and null are 2 very different things. You have a primitive type, thus zero. And printing zero means nothing is printed for that variable.

Comment: The char \u0000 refers to char NULL. So it cannot be printed as a string.

Comment: "but the default value should be print." <- Why do you think that?

Comment: Don't confuse printing the value of '\u0000' and the String "\u0000".

Answer (score 4):

A `char` with value `0` is the NUL character. It is a [non-printing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) character and does not display as anything. Traditionally, C-style strings use a NUL character to mark the end of a string.

Note that the NUL character is different from the Java `null`. NUL is a primitive `char` value, while `null` is a reference value. The `char` type cannot hold a value of `null`, but an object type like `java.lang.Character` can.

If you want to print the *numeric* value of a `char`, cast it to `int` first.